# Storing additional data to mail in IMAP

Tags: android, email, metadata, imap, thunderbird

## Introduction

I have a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

## x: High level goal

I have dream: I want to store additional data to mails which are in IMAP. I the long run I want to be able to access this data via thunderbird and k9 (android app (mail use agent)).

Use cases:

- I want to store a note in html format for this mail.
- Upload a PDF file for this mail.
- I want to store a re-submission date on the mail. Like google inbox snooze feature: Move the mail to a "do later" folder until the date is reached. (Evaluating this date and moving the mail to inbox again is not part of this question)

But I have no clue how to store additional data

## y: My current thoughts about solving it

I need a way to identify a message in IMAP. I think the message id (without folder name) should work. I know that message IDs can have duplicates, but I see no other way. Please leave a comment, if you have a better idea.

Now I need a way to store this mapping somewhere:

```
`user@imapserver:message-id` --> `additional-data`
```

## Question

How to store this mapping, so that thunderbird and k9 could access it?

Of course I know that thunderbird and k9 can't access this data today. How to patch them is a different question.

## Background

I like free software and I like free communication. Up to now I use WhatsApp, Threema and other tools. But in the long run I want a free (like in software) solution. Email is wide spread, and I think it makes more sense to improve email than to create something new.

Comment: The proper way to refer to a message long term is (Folder, UIDVALIDITY, UID), but this isn't robust against folder moves.   The only real way to store arbitrary data on most folders is via flags (STORE and FETCH), if the server supports arbitrary flags; however, many servers don't scale well to thousands of different flags, or to very long flags.  Storing a PDF is pretty much right out.   There is a `METADATA` extension defined for IMAP in RFC 5464, but I don't know any server that implements it.

Comment: You could store annotations in a parallel mailbox as MIME messages using APPEND.  You'd have to figure out a way to map annotations from one message to another (using the message-id as the subject or a transformation of the message id as the message id, at least something that you can search for efficiently).

Comment: The Resubmit date can probably be stored as an arbitrary flag, if your server supports it, if you're clever about the encoding and remove it when you're done.

Comment: (And separately, you are aware of Jabber, which is a free implementation of IM?)

Comment: @Max yes I am aware of jabber and other user-to-user messaging solution. Most people are reachable via email. Only very few are reachable via jabber. Back to this question. AFAIK jabber can't store additional data to a message, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Max your solution with a parallel folder sounds good. Please write it as answer (not as comment). Thank you.

Comment: I've added it as an answer.  As for email vs jabber: if your goal is to get people to use new communication methods, you'll have just as much trouble getting people to use your new email additions as you would have getting them to install a jabber client ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store annotations in a parallel mailbox as MIME messages using APPEND. You'd have to figure out a way to map annotations from one message to another.

So you can find the related message easily, you'll want it easy to search for.  You could do something like using the message-id of the source message as the subject of the annotation message, or a transformation of the message id as the message id of the destination message.

Comment: Yes, this looks good. IMAP APPEND will create a new mail in a mailbox. I guess I will create a new folger "meta". I think it is best to store additional data in own message per mail. If I want to store metadata for 10 mails, then there will be 10 additional mails in folder "meta".

Answer (score 2):

Here are my thoughts on it... here is the current proposed and accepted standard for IMAP4 which is the current version...

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501

Here is a wiki link to show the previous versions and the progress that has been made over time ...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol#IMAP4

I think the question is a good one, but maybe if your idea is good enough, contact the people that are in charge of the protocol and think about ways to potentially make IMAP5 with the kinds of functionality that you want to expand it to be able to utilize...

I would say that the best way would be to try making the IMAP protocol better. Read over all of the functionality that it currently supports and make suggestions to the group in charge of it. The additions that you are wanting to add sound great, but unless I misunderstood the question, I think that protocol updates might be the cleanest approach.

Sounds cool though.

Good luck... I hope you like my thoughts.

Comment: There already is a method for extending IMAP.  See http://www.iana.org/assignments/imap-capabilities/imap-capabilities.xhtml for all extensions currently defined.  The correct extension for his request is METADATA, but it is not widely deployed.  That is more the problem with IMAP than anything else: Beyond the baseline and a few common extensions, most servers do the bare minimum.

Answer (score -3):

Have you considered Mailgun?  It has an extensive API ( https://documentation.mailgun.com/api_reference.html#api-reference).  Incoming messages can be stored, processed by your application and then sent via email.  I believe you can add your own header field information (perhaps generating something like a GUID and using it for unique message tracking).  Up to 10,000 emails/month are free (one of your preferences).  If your application workflow and the API align, this might help get the job done.

Comment: No I have not considered Mailgun. I try to avoid vender lock-in.